# Haskell installing DPH package

Tags: haskell

Newbie here, I need to install the DPH library for my course, but I'm not really sure how. I follow this link: https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Data_Parallel_Haskell#Where_to_get_it , but when I run `cabal install dph-examples` this is the result:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: dph-examples-0.7.0.5 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of dph-examples-0.7.0.5)
rejecting: base-4.8.2.0/installed-0d6... (conflict: dph-examples =>
base==4.6.*)
rejecting: base-4.9.1.0, 4.9.0.0, 4.8.2.0, 4.8.1.0, 4.8.0.0, 4.7.0.2, 4.7.0.1,
4.7.0.0, 4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0, 4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0, 4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0,
4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0, 4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0, 3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global
constraint requires installed instance)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

Something tells me this didn't go as planned, I am unsure of what to do now.

Comment: I think you most likely have the wrong version of GHC installed. The page you linked to says you need GHC 7.4. Instead of installing this particular version manually, I would recommend using [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) to install `dph-examples` which will manage the version of GHC along with dependencies better than cabal by itself.

Comment: Alright, how would I go about installing DPH with stack or does it come with the installation of stack? Forgive me, but I'm new to installing packages using the terminal